# Need to find the slope of an abline from irregular curve in r

Tags: r

I am a Surgeon doing research on coronary artery bypass blood flow and am intrested in determining the peak rate of change of flow measured by transit time flow measurement (an ultrasound technology).  I am new to R and not hugely mathematically minded so apologies if this is basic.  I have been through the SO archives and dint find anything that answers my questions.

Essentially I am looking at about 2000 flow curves that are irregularly shaped and identifying the highest rate of change of flow.  I have successfully done this and can reproducibly plot an abline on a plot of the flow curve.  I am trying to determine some code that will enable to me determine the slope of this line (as I anticipate that the higher the rate of change the increased risk of bypass graft failure in the mid term).  I have been going at this for and can't conceptualise how I would use the lm() function to do this.  Below is what I have achieved so far:

```
  systole_flow_c<- structure(list(Flow_time = c(56.3977112530061, 56.4026867899494, 
56.4076623268928, 56.4126378638361, 56.4176134007795, 56.4225889377229, 
56.4275644746662, 56.4325400116096, 56.4375155485529, 56.4424910854963, 
56.4474666224397, 56.452442159383, 56.4574176963264, 56.4623932332698, 
56.4673687702131, 56.4723443071565, 56.4773198440998, 56.4822953810432, 
56.4872709179866, 56.4922464549299, 56.4972219918733, 56.5021975288167, 
56.50717306576, 56.5121486027034, 56.5171241396467, 56.5220996765901, 
56.5270752135335, 56.5320507504768, 56.5370262874202, 56.5420018243635, 
56.5469773613069, 56.5519528982503, 56.5569284351936, 56.561903972137, 
56.5668795090804, 56.5718550460237, 56.5768305829671, 56.5818061199104, 
56.5867816568538, 56.5917571937972, 56.5967327307405, 56.6017082676839, 
56.6066838046273, 56.6116593415706, 56.616634878514, 56.6216104154573, 
56.6265859524007, 56.6315614893441), Flow = c(102.154783904552, 
104.65869307518, 105.074375867844, 101.994127035141, 93.7577188014984, 
80.5349797010422, 64.1021206974983, 44.0539047122002, 22.8391271084547, 
1.58900616224855, -17.1908847987652, -30.3368531167507, -37.4533385038376, 
-36.3606214523315, -28.083061799407, -11.967372149229, 10.1667772978544, 
33.9673832058907, 56.2577210366726, 73.6899748444557, 85.1335451006889, 
88.36430311203, 83.1641033291817, 70.4614445567131, 51.6762435436249, 
29.7329295426607, 6.72542629763484, -15.294348821044, -34.7450114786625, 
-50.8976839482784, -63.5180175304413, -72.5835934281349, -78.4044042229652, 
-81.1443626880646, -81.1894536018372, -78.9461731910706, -74.4699835777283, 
-68.5452073812485, -62.0530433952808, -55.7536818087101, -50.0871911644936, 
-45.2259816229343, -40.9968197345734, -37.1948555111885, -33.3057753741741, 
-28.6770667880774, -22.9764748364687, -15.9981865435839)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))

    #find peak gradient flow in systole
    d1<-diff(systole_flow_c$Flow)/diff(systole_flow_c$Flow_time)
    max_dfdt<-max(d1)
    d1_poss<-as.numeric(which.max(diff(systole_flow_c$Flow)/diff(systole_flow_c$Flow_time)))
    plot(systole_flow_c$Flow_time,systole_flow_c$Flow, type="l")
    abline(systole_flow_c$Flow[d1_poss]-systole_flow_c$Flow_time[d1_poss]*d1[d1_poss],d1[d1_poss])
```

I would be grateful for any help

OS - macOS BigSur V11.2.3
RStudio - Version 1.4.1103

Comment: `max_dfdt` is the slope of the line, no?

Comment: The `lm` function would help fit a linear model; this would be useful if you're looking for the slope through a subset of noisy data. Is that the case here?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you are trying to find the point on the curve where the slope is maximum and determine which is it. This is not the same as finding the line which is the best fit (least squares estimator) for a set of points. Therefore, I don't think the `lm()` makes much sense in this case. I think your approach, which is purelly analytical is ok. The `lm()` helps to build a statistical model, based on some hypothesis, etc. Here I belive you don't need that, and you just want to maximize some quantity, the derivative of the curve.

Comment: `max_dfdt` is also `d1[d1_poss]`.  The latter is passed as the second argument to `abline` and, from the online doc, this defines the slope of the line.  So I think you have what you need already.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi everyone, Many thanks for the input.  I think my question shows the danger of a little bit of knowledge! You are correct that my question is purely analytical and I already had the data I needed.  Apologies for using up you time but again, many thanks for the help and support! I wanted to plot the abline as a visual quality control as earlier parts of the code (not included here) are identifying different phases of the cardiac cycle, I think the visual confirmation that this is correct was important (although maybe not necessary) for me.  Regards,  Campbell